# AMAVIS discarding emails instead of tagging them or moving them to quarantine

Tags: amavis

I'm seeing many emails being discarded from my system.
I'm per-user policies and have the following options set:
spam_tag_level = -9999
spam_tag2_level = 7 (roughly - it changes on a per-user basis)
spam_tag3_level = 25
spam_kill_level = 40
spam_dsn_cutoff_level = 999
spam_quarantine_cutoff_level = 999

What I want is for all emails which are spam to be tagged that way in the subject, or at most quarantined, but I don't want any rejected/discarded.

Please can you provide thoughts on how to make this work as I want it to?

Thank you!

EDIT: I'm seeing my amavisd sql return 0s in place of my spam_tag_level etc. - anyone experienced this before? When I look in the database, it's correctly set to -9999 for spam_tag_level etc. and it does say in the logs that it finds a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was that I had used DBI for mysql when I am using MariaDB.
I needed to use DBI:MariaDB instead of DBI:mysql

To get this working, I needed to install the DBD:MariaDB package:
cpan DBD::MariaDB

I also had to stop the spamassassin daemon when using amavisd to fix a few other minor inconveniences